# Template for reusable Django app is not rendering

Tags: python, django

I have a separate app, and I'd like to render its template.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^guestbook/', include('guestbook.urls', namespace='guestbook', app_name='guestbook'))
]
```

**guestbook/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**guestbook/views.py**

```
def index(request):
    entries = Entry.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    return render(request, 'guestbook/index.html', {'entries': entries})
```

**templates/guestbook/index.html**

```
{% extends 'guestbook/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<a href="{% url 'guestbook:add_comment' entry.pk %}">Comment</a></span>
{% endblock %}
```

But I'm getting error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /guestbook/
Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

0 pattern(s) tried: []

```
Error during template rendering
In template /Users/bulrathi/Yandex.Disk.localized/Learning/Code/Test tasks/myproject/templates/guestbook/index.html, error at line 27
Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

27 <span class="meta-chunk"><a href="{% url 'guestbook:add_comment' entry.pk %}">Комментировать</a></span>
```

I'll be so grateful for advice.

Comment: What middleware is installed. It looks like there is login functionality (possibly in guestbook/base.html) that is not initialized properly.

Comment: thanks corriganjc, your comment solved my issue

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. Any chance you could put what you found in an answer to help the next people that have this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in base.html template. There were such hrefs as `<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Выйти</a>` and `<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Войти</a>`. Changing them to `<a href="{% url 'guestbook:logout' %}">Выйти</a>` and `<a href="{% url 'guestbook:login' %}">Войти</a>` solved the problem.